# Laravel form inputs -how to enable/disable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i am able to insert data in mysql database using laravel form, i want to have THREE buttons under this form, (Enable/Disable/save). when i click on enable all textbox/checkbox etc should be editable, when click on save it should save edited data, when i click on disable everything should be disabled just readonly.
is it possible in laravel, **can you please tell me how? any link/example?**

Comment: this is html's feature not php's, do it by js

Comment: @C2486 Thankyou, any link to learn everything which might help in this scenario?

Comment: share your html ? i will give answer.